# Let $\Sigma$ be any symmetrix, positive definite matrix. partition $\Sigma$ and $\Sigma^{-1}$ as follows:

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics

$$ \Sigma = 
        \begin{pmatrix}
        \Sigma_{11} & \Sigma_{12} \\
        \Sigma^T_{12} & \Sigma_{22} 
        \end{pmatrix}
$$
$$\Sigma^{-1} = 
        \begin{pmatrix}
        \Sigma^{11} & \Sigma^{12} \\
        (\Sigma^{12})^T & \Sigma^{22} 
        \end{pmatrix}
$$

Show that
$$(\Sigma^{22})^{-1} \Sigma^{21} = -\Sigma_{21} \Sigma^{-1}_{11}$$

So I'm not really familiar with the notation presented. My textbook doesn't go into it much either (and when it does it references this problem).

For starters, what does it mean to have something like $\Sigma^{11}$ as opposed to $\Sigma_{11}$?

And can anyone guide me on how to solve this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: $\Sigma_{11}$ is the upper-left block of $\Sigma$.$\Sigma^{11}$ is just the upper-left block of $\Sigma^{-1}$. Also, by $\Sigma_{21}$, did you mean $\Sigma_{12}$?

Comment: No. It is written as $\Sigma_{21}$ in my text. But I think it's equivalent to say $\Sigma_{21} = \Sigma_{12}^T$

Comment: I wonder if it doesn't want me to take the inverse of one of the partitions?

Comment: I tried multiplying the two together and setting the matrix product equal to the identity matrix. I then assumed the individual terms were equal to the terms of the identity matrix. For row 2 column 1 I get the following:

$\Sigma_{22}(\Sigma^{12})^T = -\Sigma_{12}^{T} \Sigma^{11}$

Is there some mathematical knowledge on what step to take next? Am I wrong to assume that $\Sigma_{12}^T = \Sigma_{21}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Writing out the product $\Sigma^{-1} \Sigma = I$, we see that (looking at the 2nd row of $\Sigma^{-1}$ times the first column of $\Sigma$) we must have 
\begin{align*}
\Sigma^{21} \Sigma_{11} + \Sigma^{22} \Sigma_{21} = 0 \implies \\\Sigma_{11}^{-1} = -((\Sigma^{21})^{-1}\Sigma^{22} \Sigma_{21})^{-1} = -\Sigma_{21}^{-1} (\Sigma^{22})^{-1} \Sigma^{21}.
\end{align*}
Multiplying both sides on the left by $-\Sigma_{21}$ gives us the answer.

Comment: Ah I was close! Thank you so much!

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to math stack exchange. If this answer or any others solve your issues, please mark it as accepted.

Comment: Oh wait. Quick question. Looking at the last part of your proof, is it equivalent to say $\Sigma_{21}^{-1} = \Sigma^{21}$? Or am I misunderstanding something?

Edit: Wrote lower case sigmas! :(

Comment: You know, I just found a theorem relating to this:
http://fourier.eng.hmc.edu/e161/lectures/gaussianprocess/node7.html

In my textbook a similar theorem appears for the covariance matrix of a conditional distribution written $\Sigma_{1 . 2}$ (not sure how to format but the . isn't a decimal. It's right in the center)
The above equals:
$\Sigma_{11} - \Sigma_{12}\Sigma_{22}^{-1}\Sigma_{12}^T$

Comment: Wait, nevermind, the proof still works, because when you left-multiply, $\Sigma_{21}$ just cancels with its inverse. You probably got confused when I took the inverse of the product of three matrices. It is common knowledge that the inverse of a product of matrices, is the product of the inverses of the matrices in reverse order, which is why $\Sigma_{21}^{-1}$ appears on the left side (it was originally on the right side).

Comment: Oh very well. Truthfully I had forgotten this. More mature me regrets Undergraduate me's indifference to linear algebra.

I think at first I didn't grasp that you took the inverse of both sides. Now I definitely got it. Thank you!